# comparison of negative numbers turn out wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing a test of position bounding boxes, but when comparing negative (south or west) positions with other negative positions it turns the result upside down.

```
if minlat > maxlat:
    minlat, maxlat = swap(minlat, maxlat)
if minlon > maxlon:
    minlon, maxlon = swap(minlon, maxlon)
```

This works fine when comparing latitudes on northern hemisphere or positions on southern with northern hemisphere, but when comparing positions on southern hemisphere it turns them around (i.e., -20.4 is less than -20.8). Is there a simple solution to this, or must I make a different test if both values are less than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if float(minlat) > float(maxlat):`

Making sure the compared numbers are actually numbers and not string objects. Comparing string objects using less than or greater than can have strange results.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I'll edit the answer to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

generally you'll want to compare the absolute values rather than the actual values in this scenario, try

```
if abs(minlat) > abs(maxlat):
```

good luck!

Comment: I was trying to compare the actual values (-3 > -5, -3 < 5, 3 < 5, etc.), but your example gave me the hint to actually check wether they were numbers (for some reason they had been passed as str() ). Got them forced as floating numbers now, so it should work.